# Replace matrix rows conditionally while avoiding For loop

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have the following variables:

```
myMatrix={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}
myIndices={1,3}
```

I need to replace the rows `myIndices` of `myMatrix` with rows that contain a `1` at the position of the row number. The final result should be:

```
myMatrixFinal={{1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}
```

How can I do this functionally, without a For loop? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set[myMatrix[[#, #]], 1] & /@ myIndices;
```

Or:

```
ReplacePart[myMatrix, {{#, #} & /@ myIndices -> 1}]
```

Or:

```
SparseArray[({#, #} -> 1 & /@ myIndices), Dimensions@myMatrix] // Normal
```

Comment: @space_voyager Thanks for the accept, but I'd wait for a while and see what other people come up with. There's a whole lot of smarter folks than me here!

Comment: Alright! I'm still not used to people here being so open to what others have in store!

Answer (score 6):

```
f = MapAt[1&, #, Thread[{#2, #2}]] &;

f[myMatrix, myIndices]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myMatrixFinal = ReplacePart[myMatrix, {#, #} & /@ myIndices -> 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(myMatrix[[#, #]] = 1) & /@ myIndices;
```

Comment: Pure functions with assignments-as-side-effect tickle my fancy for some reason.

Comment: In my mind, they're scary things - I even fear to use them in `Scan`. A "pure function" is meant to be "pure"!

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

p = {1, 3};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1) and `ReplicateLayer` (new in 11.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> 1, ReplicateLayer[2, 2] @ p] @ m
```

{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `SubsetMap`:

```
m = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

p = {1, 3};

SubsetMap[{1, 1} &, m, Floor@ReplicateLayer[2, 2]@p]

(*{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}*)
```